# Implement Navigation Drawer Animation Without Using AppCompat V7

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, drawerlayout

I want to use the following animation in `DrawerLayout` [image]

But without using `AppCompat V7` because I am only developing from `Android L` and above. So, how should I do it.

Comment: Using appcompat v7, the animation can be applied using the theme you apply to the app or toolbar. Are you aware of it?

Comment: @Dhaval: I am not trying to use AppCompat V7. I am developing from Android L only.

Answer (score 0):

source code for your implementation is already available code on [github](https://github.com/ChrisRenke/DrawerArrowDrawable).  hope this will help you.

Comment: Since it is backport for lower version than Android L. I guess now I have to search on the source code as it must be present on Android L